# Rails 3 nested layouts: how to add at the end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

Is it possible to manipulate the placeholders so that I can not only set their content, but also add/remove content in a particular order? For example:

layouts/base.html.erb (a base layout meant to be extended):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title><%= yield :title %></title>
    <%= yield :stylesheets %>
    <%= yield :javascripts %>
    <%= yield :csrf %>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <%= yield :header %>

      <%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>

      <%= yield :footer %>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

layouts/application.html.erb (this is the layout I will be using for the most part of my app, it inherits from the base layout):

```
<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<% end %>

<% content_for :javascripts do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<% end %>

<% content_for :csrf do %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<% end %>

<%= render :template => 'layouts/base' %>
```

Now I want a layout for a specific controller, which may need to add more javascript links, or maybe completely remove them. Let's say I want to add only one file **after** the other javascripts. So far I got this:

layouts/some_controller.html.erb (this is a layout for a particular controller, it should inherit from the application layout):

```
<% content_for :javascripts do %>
  <script src="/assets/some_javascript_that_depends_on_jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% end %>

<%= render :template => 'layouts/application' %>
```

This won't work, because it will place some_javascript_that_depends_on_jquery.js at the beginning of the :javascripts placeholder, and I need it at the end because it depends on jquery.

It would suck to have to extend the base layout directly, and keep track of any change made to the application layout to apply it to the controller-specific layout too.

What would be the recommended way to deal with this situation?

Comment: I would probably just rename the controller javascripts to local_javascripts and yield that too in the base but I guess that is what you want to avoid. (Or local_header maybe? I find myself wanting to have "local" stylesheets also at times.)

Comment: @froderik That would work, but doesn't feel right and will end up being a mess as soon as I need more controller-specific layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done as in other frameworks where you just extend layouts and then modify the inherited blocks at will.

Rails sort of forces you to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

In application.html.erb, Keep the contents of content_for :javascripts in a partial

Here your partial will have 
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

Then, call the same partial in addition with other javascripts in other layout.

Another way,

You can call one helper which will have a hash like this:
js_files = {"application_controller" => ["js_file_1"], "some_controller" => ["js_file_1","js_file_2"]}

Now, fetch the js files and construct the javascript include tag in run time based on controller in your content for.

Hope this will be more flexible.
Sorry for not formatting.

Comment: Wouldn't that add the application's javascripts twice?

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the second way will only work for constructable things. I need to be able to add all kinds of content, the js tag was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Always keep one js file per controller.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

lets take example of `users` controller then there will be `users.js.coffee` file.

If you want to have multiple js files for users controller then you can require those files inside users.js.coffee file

> vi users.js.coffee

```
//= require 'a'
//= require 'b'

/* my extra js code will go here */
```